# How do I secure a WCF Service, hosted in IIS, using BasicHttp binding, and NO SSL Cert?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Is it possible to configure a WCF service that:

1. is hosted by IIS
2. uses the `basicHttpBinding` binding
3. does not need an SSL cert
4. supports sessions (`ServiceContract(SessionMode:=ServiceModel.SessionMode.Required)`)

I know the easiest thing to do would be to buy an SSL cert, but for reasons beyond my control I am being required to match the 4 constraints above.

thanks,

Tom

Comment: This is a no-go - `basicHttpBinding` does **not** support sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell your boss that `basicHttpBinding` supports real security only when using with SSL certificate (otherwise all data are passed as a plain text) and it doesn't support WCF sessions out of the box. WCF session is dependent on either:

- Transport session (only netTcp or netNamedPipe bindings)
- Reliable session (only netTcp, wsHttp or custom bindings)
- Security session (only wsHttp or custom bindings and it requires either windows authentication or SSL certificate)

Sessions can be probably added by building your own service behavior and replacing `IInstaceContextProvider` and perhaps also `IInstanceProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This answer ended up being the leverage I needed to get my environment to acquire SSL certs for our internal servers.